# IndexError when reversing an array in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, reverse

I tried to reverse an array in Python, but I got an `IndexError: list index out of range`. Can anyone help me find out what's my problem?

Here's my code:

```py
def reverseArray(a,n):
    b = []
    
    for i in range(n + 1):
        b.insert(0, a[i])
    
    return b
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/submission/20220709/03/24/hackerrank-6dc9d7d54d580ec91f519f2a6455587b/code/Solution.py", line 33, in <module>
    res = reverseArray(arr,arr_count)
  File "/tmp/submission/20220709/03/24/hackerrank-6dc9d7d54d580ec91f519f2a6455587b/code/Solution.py", line 21, in reverseArray
    b.insert(0, a[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `reverseArray` is the call which caused the issue, let's fix it first

Refactoring your code we get :

```py
def reverseArray(a, n):  # rather unpythonic
    b = []
    for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
        b.append(a[i])
    return b
```

Which works like this taking two arguments :

```py
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]      
>>> reverseArray(foo, 3)
[3, 2, 1]
```

But that is unpythonic and can be alot better, something like this :

```py
def reversed_array(a):
    return [*reversed(a)]
```

Which is exactly the same thing except it takes one less argument of length
Example use :

```py
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> reversed_array(foo) 
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the list "b" **doesn't contain** any element , so `b.insert(0,a[i])` **won't work** .
What you have to do instead is , use `b.append(a[i])` , which in your case , will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it like this:

```
reverseArray([], 0)
reverseArray([1, 2, 3], 3)
```

The actually problem is:

```
range(n + 1)
```

Cause range creates sequence from 0 to n - 1:

```
range(0) # empty seq
range(3) # 0, 1, 2
```

So you simply need do it like this:

```
def reverseArray(a: list, n: int):
    b = []
    
    for i in range(n): 
        b.insert(0, a[i])
    
    return b
```

But there is shorter, faster and more pythonic way to do it:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
reversed_a = a[::-1]
>>> reversed_a
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a quick and "pythonic" way to reverse an array in Python. You can use the **Array Slicing**. Put a pair of brackets after your array just like calling an element. For example, `list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. You can use the array slicing to reverse it like this: `list = list[::-1]`. This is a very use ful skill in Python, and it's capable for all iterable items. For more informations about slicing in Python, [see here](https://www.askpython.com/python/array/array-slicing-in-python).

Array slicing is just a simple way to reverse. Now let's get back to our question. The goal is to reverse the given array. Instead of the normal hard way, we can *think the problem reversely*. In your original code you were enumerating the array from start to end, which is a hard way to control the index of the array. Now let's enumerate it from back to start. So `for i in range(n + 1)` can be replaced with `for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1)`. This line of code enumerates from -1 to 0. Inside the for-loop, you can directly add `a[i]` in `b` (Because is in reverse order). After that, the code for this method will be:

```py
def reverse_array(array):    # Follow PEP8!
    res_array = []
    for i in range(len(array) - 1, -1, -1):
        res_array.append(array[i])
    return res_array
```

And here's an example:

```
>>> example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> reverse_array(example)
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```